# How do I call codeigniter function in ajax looping

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my AJaX code I want to use CodeIgniter function

```php
<?php echo $controller->timestamp(data[i].published);?>
```

But it is not working

```js
function show_draft(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>ct_backend/show_draft',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',               
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                html +='<div class="media dashboard-draft-each">'+
                '<div class="media-body custom-form-button">'+
                '<ul>'+
                '<li class="dropdown">'+
                '<a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">'+
                '<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></span>'+
                '</a>'+
                '<div class="dropdown-menu">'+
                '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item draft-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'"><span class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></span> Edit</a>'+
                '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item draft-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete</a>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '<a href="javascript:;" data="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</a>'+
                '<p>'+data[i].description+'</p>'+
                '<span class="far fa-clock"> '+<?php echo $controller->timestamp(data[i].published);?>+'</span>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';                                       
            }
            $('#show_draft').html(html);
        },
        error: function(){
            Toast();
            function Toast (){
                var priority = 'danger';
                var title    = 'Error';
                var message  = 'Could not get Data from Database!';
                $.toaster({ priority : priority, title : title, message : message });
            }
        }
    });
}//end Show draft
```

Comment: You can't. Php runs only on server and javascript runs only in browser and neither knows anything about the other. The `success` callback runs long after the page has been sent to browser where php doesn't exist. Add the timestamp data server side to what gets sent in the json

Comment: Also note you should never ever use `async:false` . It is a horrible practice and has been deprecated by the browser vendors. You should be seeing deprecation warnings in browser dev tools console when you do use it

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't know what is `data[i]`

Comment: So sir which code i may use?

Comment: Use your codeigniter model (or controller) to modify the published value before sending the json then get rid of that echo and use javascript to concatenate the modified published string the same way you do all the other property values

Comment: if you are in `.js` file then define `base_url` first. as a variable. like `var base_url = 'localhost/mysite/'` then use like `url: base_url + "ct_backend/show_draft",`

Comment: Also let us know `what error you got in network tab`.

Comment: Thanks sir, <?php echo $controller->timestamp(data[i].published);?> I want put  data[i].published variable in codeigniter timestamp function and also want to return value.